# log4net creating file but not writing

Tags: c#, log4net

I have this console application that writes to a file for all the events and when new month starts it creates a new file when I run the console application directly it creates a new file on month change and write to it but when I try to call this console application from another c# winform application it only creates the log file on month change but write to the old file after that

```
var appender = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()0];
                    appender.File = string.Empty;
                    appender.File = @"H:/FolderName/" + FileName+ "/" + 
                 DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMM") + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year+".txt";
                    appender.ActivateOptions();
```

Comment: my guess is a permissions problem. Use procmon to see whats happening

Comment: both calling and called application are on my local desktop . it creates that new file but keeps writing to the old month file